# Magento 1.13 FPC cache not getting invalidated

Tags: magento, caching, magento-fpc

We are using Magento 1.13 EE, memcache and APC op code cache.

Any text change made to the static cms page / static block is getting reflected immediately in the front end and in cache management FPC is showing the status as "enabled" and not as "invalidated".

Also the page load speed is slow. Seems FPC is not working. But every time the /var/full_page_cache/ folder is cleared, the folders gets rebuild and grows in size.

How to check whether the content is really rendered from FPC?

Could anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

public function extractContent($content)
    {

is the function in Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor that is supposed to extract content from FPC folder depending on request params.

Do some file write code within tis function code and log what content is returned.
if content is NULL then FPC is not working.